# Correct way to initialize wrapper Integer

Tags: java, integer

I have a drop down field in application which displays numbers.

When user doesn't select any value from drop down, I would want to insert as null to database.

How can I initialize an Integer wrapper class to null?

I have tried as

```
 Integer  days = new Integer(null);
        if (request.getParameter("days").equals("")) {
        } else {
            days  = 
                    Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("days"));
        }
```

However I am getting the following error, so what is the correct method in declaring Integer variable?

```
NumberFormatException at test.doPost(Controller.java:23);
```

How to initialize an Integer variable so that if no values are selected by user then null should get inserted.

Comment: Did you try to print and see what value do you get for `request.getParameter("days")`?

Comment: maybe not initiate it -  Integer  days;

Comment: @RohitJain It is empty(null)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should initialize with null:

```
    Integer  days = null;
    if (request.getParameter("days") != null && !request.getParameter("days").isEmpty()) {
        days = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("days"));
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Better to validate its an integer first:

```
    Integer  days = null;
    if(request.getParameter("days")!=null && request.getParameter("days").matches("^\\d+$"))
    {
        days = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("days"));
    }
```

**UPDATE 2: To be able to insert null in DB:**

```
if (project.getDays() != null)
   callablestatement.setInt(2, project.getDays());
else 
   callablestatement.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Comment: @RC.: Sorry for goof up, corrected. I had a `StringUtils` doing same actually in a static method.

Comment: @RC.: Yes corrected, may be I'm tired.. I should have been careful.

Comment: Funny we can see who copy/paste answers

Comment: @Polppan you shouldn't :p Then use `.equals("")`

Comment: @Polppan: You can use `if (request.getParameter("days") != null && !request.getParameter("days").equals(""))`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for pointing this out, however when I am trying to insert the values to database, I am getting NPE at this line `callablestatement.setInt(2, project.getDays());`

Comment: But didn't you ask that you wanted to insert null in DB?

Comment: `setInt()` take an `int`, so there is an auto-unbox and a NPE. see javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int, int)

Comment: Thanks @RC. its been a while since I wrote JDBC code but couldn't OP just skip setting column 2 for null case and DB will automatically fill null in column 2.

Comment: @anubhava You mean to say that I should check for null and then conditionally set null if it is null or appropriate value?

Comment: it should be like this: `if (project.getDays()!=null) callablestatement.setInt(2, project.getDays());` DB will automatically fill null in column 2 if you don't set its value in column 2

Comment: @anubhava if `project.getDays()` is null, then it is throwing error, perhaps I need if else statement? Error-  `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2`

Comment: May be you can try: `if (project.getDays()!=null) callablestatement.setInt(2, project.getDays()); else callablestatement.setInt(2, null);`

Comment: @anubhava Yes it does, but then I will have to change variable type to String from Integer.

Comment: Ok just found out it is: **`callablestatement.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);`**
`

Comment: No you don't need to change variable type

Comment: @anubhava ah So if it is null then call `callablestatement.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);` ?

Comment: @anubhava Thank you, appreciated for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. I also learnt about this `setNull` method for answering your question. +1 to your question as well.

Comment: `callablestatement.setObject(2, project.getDays());` should also work

Comment: @RC. yes with `setObject` I do not need to have `if else` condition. Thanks

Comment: @RC. I presume that with `setObject` it is totally safe to use and no problems with NPE.

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
Integer days = null;
String param = request.getParameter("days");
if (param != null && !"".equals(param)) {
   days  = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("days"));
}
```

Comment: No such method `String#empty()`

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the days object to `null` and then checking to see if the days object is `null` or is empty:

```
Integer days = null;
if (request.getParameter("days") != null && !request.getParameter("days").isEmpty()) {
    // rest of code.
```

Comment: Thanks blackpanther for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trust the value of the days parameter in the request.
What if some client will pass an invalid value? (a non-number string).
For this reason you should catch `NumberFormatException` when you try to parse the parameter value.

```
Integer days = null;
String parameterValue = request.getParameter("days");
if (parameterValue != null && !parameterValue.isEmpty()) {
  try {
    days = Integer.parseInt(parameterValue);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // log or something
  }
}
```

Comment: No such method `String.empty()` (`parameterValue.empty()`)

Comment: Thanks Itay Karo for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the declaration on which others have commented.

You are getting `NumberFormatException` because `request.getParameter("days")` is returning a non integer value text or null. parseInt method throws  `NumberFormatException` when it gets a string input which is not a valid integer value.

Comment: Thanks Juned Ahsan for your help.

Answer (score 1):

With a try/catch:

```
Integer days = null;
try {
    days = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("days"));
} catch (final NumberFormatException ex) {
    // ignore
}
```

or with guava [`Ints`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#tryParse%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Integer days = null;
final String param = request.getParameter("days");
if (param != null) {
    days = Ints.tryParse(param);
}
```

This way, you avoid the `NumberFormatException` if "days" is not parsable.

Comment: mistake in my copy/paste.

Comment: I'm not the only one making copy/paste mistake today :P

Comment: But if OP validates using `request.getParameter("days").matches("^\\d+$")` then it shouldn't throw `NumberFormatException` right?

Comment: @anubhava yes, it's ok as long as "days" is positive

Comment: @RC While inserting into db I am getting NPE.